# Why IS NULL in WHERE clause is not working in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null, nullable

I have just started practicing Big Query but facing a problem for filtering out non-null records.

I am using `usertype IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, it throws no error just says that "There is no data to display." but there are multiple null records in a dataset.

```
ColName    Type     Mode
---------------------------    
usertype   STRING   NULLABLE
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
WHERE usertype IS NULL;
```

Result:

> There is no data to display.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: is there any row where usertype is null? I mean data in the table. What's your table name? The .new_york_citibike.citibike_trips is?

Comment: The data is not null it is an empty string in the citibrike_trips dataset, try the following select 
  distinct usertype
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
where usertype = ''

Comment: in this table there is no rows with `usertype is null` - rather use `WHERE usertype = ''`

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Zagales, it works. I didn't notice that it is an empty STRING and spent an hour on this.

Comment: @learning - Yes table is .new_york_citibike.citibike_trips. Since those rows were empty, I was using the IS NULL but now, It's resolved.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail Berlyant.